# MapKit addAnnotations: not working

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, mapkit

I have code:

```
if (self.annotations) [self.mapView addAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];
NSLog(@"mapView: %@, anos:%@",self.mapView,self.mapView.annotations);
```

And I get the next output form log:

```
2012-04-26 14:35:53.823 FlickrClient[46441:11603] mapView: <MKMapView: 0x79c8b50; frame = (0 0; 320 367); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x79c62b0>>, anos:(
)
```

So as far as I understand the annotations are not added to the `mapView`
Also before this code, I have the next logging stuff:

```
for (id i in self.annotations)
{
    NSLog(@"%@, %i",i,[i conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MKAnnotation)]);
}
```

and it gives:

```
...
2012-04-26 14:35:53.766 FlickrClient[46441:11603] <TopPlaceAnnotation: 0x6d8a590>, 1
2012-04-26 14:35:53.767 FlickrClient[46441:11603] <TopPlaceAnnotation: 0x6d8a5a0>, 1
2012-04-26 14:35:53.767 FlickrClient[46441:11603] <TopPlaceAnnotation: 0x6d8a5b0>, 1
2012-04-26 14:35:53.819 FlickrClient[46441:11603] <TopPlaceAnnotation: 0x6d8a5c0>, 1
2012-04-26 14:35:53.819 FlickrClient[46441:11603] <TopPlaceAnnotation: 0x6d8a5d0>, 1
2012-04-26 14:35:53.819 FlickrClient[46441:11603] <TopPlaceAnnotation: 0x6d8a5e0>, 1
...
```

So `self.annotations` exist and all conform to `MKAnnotation`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think there is a small mistake,

this line:

```
if (self.annotations) [self.mapView addAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];
```

should be:

```
if (self.annotations) [self.mapView addAnnotations:self.annotations];
```